# take value from another input without refreshing page in php

Tags: javascript, ajax

i have this fetch.php file

```
 $out='';
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
 $out .=  '<option value='.$row["jam_mulai"].'>' .$row["jam_mulai"]. '-.$row["jam_berakhir"].'</option>'; 
} 
 echo $out;
```

and i want to take the data from the option value to another select option in different file.
to this input.php file

```
 <select class="form-control select2" name="nama_dokter" style="width: 100%;" id="nama_dokter">
                        <option value="" selected="true" disabled="disabled">Pilih Dokter</option>
                    <?php
                         $query  = mysqli_query($koneksi, "SELECT * FROM jadwal_praktek LEFT JOIN dokter
                                  ON jadwal_praktek.dokter_id=dokter.id WHERE status='Aktif' GROUP BY dokter_id");
                        while ($data = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
                    ?>  

                       <option value="<?= $data['id_jadwal'];?>"><?php echo $data['nama_dkt'];?></option>
                    <?php } ?>
                    </select>
```

so i want that if jam_mulai that user choose is same with the jam_mulai and dokter_id that are already in the database, so the value of option value (input.php) will be inserted as the jadwal_id.

i have doctors (dokter_id) that have one or more than one schedule (jadwal_id) with different time (jam_mulai)

[here's the schedule table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SbbIk.png)

i know its really confusing, i also find it confusing to explain, but that what i meant. if someone may know the solution, please reply. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

fetch.php

```
$out = '';
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $out .= '<option value="' . $row["jam_mulai"] . '">' . $row["jam_mulai"] . '-' . $row["jam_berakhir"] . '</option>';
}
echo $out;
```

input.php (html and js)

```
<select class="form-control select2" name="jam_mulai" style="width: 100%;" id="jam_mulai">
    <option value="" selected="true" disabled="disabled">Pilih Jam Mulai</option>
    <!-- Fetch and populate options using AJAX -->
</select>

<select class="form-control select2" name="nama_dokter" style="width: 100%;" id="nama_dokter">
    <option value="" selected="true" disabled="disabled">Pilih Dokter</option>
    <!-- Options will be dynamically populated using JavaScript -->
</select>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.4.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        // Populate jam_mulai dropdown
        $.ajax({
            url: 'fetch.php',
            method: 'GET',
            success: function (data) {
                $('#jam_mulai').html(data);
            }
        });

        // Handle change event of jam_mulai dropdown
        $('#jam_mulai').on('change', function () {
            var selectedJamMulai = $(this).val();

            // Fetch and populate nama_dokter dropdown based on selectedJamMulai
            $.ajax({
                url: 'fetch_nama_dokter.php',
                method: 'POST',
                data: {selectedJamMulai: selectedJamMulai},
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#nama_dokter').html(data);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

fetch_name_dokter.php

```
<?php

    if (isset($_POST['selectedJamMulai'])) {
        $selectedJamMulai = $_POST['selectedJamMulai'];
        $query = mysqli_query($koneksi, "SELECT DISTINCT dokter_id, nama_dkt FROM jadwal_praktek 
                                         LEFT JOIN dokter ON jadwal_praktek.dokter_id = dokter.id 
                                         WHERE jam_mulai = '$selectedJamMulai' AND status='Aktif'");
        while ($data = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
            echo '<option value="' . $data['id_jadwal'] . '">' . $data['nama_dkt'] . '</option>';
        }
    }
    ?>
```